# I cannot reinstall Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, ide

I have a new computer with some data transferred onto it. Unfortunately, eclipse was no longer functional, so I deleted the folder with the IDE files and went to reinstall the IDE to that same folder. However, I got this error while trying to install:

```
[2021-09-24 13:26:34] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:553)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:345)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Owner_.eclipse_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/jdm23/.p2/pool.
  java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Users\jdm23\.p2\pool\plugins.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getOutputStream(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/jdm23/.p2/pool.
  java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Users\jdm23\.p2\pool\plugins.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getOutputStream(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=1003 Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Users/jdm23/.p2/pool.
  java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory C:\Users\jdm23\.p2\pool\plugins.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getOutputStream(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

It keeps repeating that last block, but you get the idea. It keeps trying to install files to a user that no longer exists on my new computer, which is likely why my new computer would not let me open the eclipse files I used to have. I tried digging around for any lingering old files that needed to be deleted, but I must be missing something, because this error still pops up. What should I do?

Comment: In case you transferred also `%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse` and/or `%USERPROFILE%\.p2`, delete them too.

Comment: @howlger Apologies for the late reply! Where would I go to delete these?

Comment: Just paste `%USERPROFILE%` into the File Explorer of Windows and it will be automatically expanded (in your case, probably to `C:\Users\jdm23`).